# Php not equal array combine

Tags: php

I can't understand how to combine these arrays.

```
$data = array("a", "b", "c")
$array = array(0 => Array(1 , 2, 3), 1 => Array(4, 5, 6))
```

I tried different functions such as merge, combine, map..

Result has to be:

```
 array(
    'a' => array(1, 4),
    'b' => array(2, 5),
    'c' => array(3, 6),
    )
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own too?

Comment: Yes of course, i typed loop just need to combined it

Comment: I cant figure out how

Comment: When you try things and they don't work, you should include descriptions of the bad results in your questions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $data = array("a", "b", "c");
    $array = array(array(1 , 2, 3), array(4, 5, 6));

    $result = array();

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        foreach($array as $innerKey => $innerValue)
            $result[$value][] = $innerValue[$key];
    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [a] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 4 )
    [b] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 5 )
    [c] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 6 )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution that uses the function [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) available since PHP 5.5:

```
$data  = array("a", "b", "c");
$array = array(0 => Array(1 , 2, 3), 1 => Array(4, 5, 6));

$result = array();
foreach($data as $i => $v) {
    $result[$v] = array_column($array, $i);
}
```

If you are stuck with a previous version then use [`Rizier123`'s solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990288/4265352) (it does the same thing with just a little more code.